# ¿Puedo utilizlar STATEMENT con referencias al igual que PREPAREDSTATEMENT?

Tags: java, sql

Con `PREPAREDSTATEMENT` se le pasan las referencias de los valores al `QUERY` pero, ¿existirá alguna manera de hacerlo con `STATEMENT`?

Con prepared statement lo hago de esta manera:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM alumons WHERE nombre = ? AND pass = ?";

System.out.println("Query => " + sql);

//Le pasamos los parametros por un ?
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, per.getNombre());
ps.setString(2, per.getPass());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, no se puede. El programador tiene que montar el SQL en un String (tampoco es tan complicdo con `MessageFormat`).

Además del programar el montar el SQL, eso implica que el programador tiene que estar atento para "desinfectar" los valores que procedan del exterior del programa para asegurarse de que no son un riesgo de inyección de SQL.

Comment: si eso ya lo hice, como puedes ver lo coloco en un String, entonces no existe una manera de desinfectar como tu dices el codigo por medio de **statement**:                                                                                   
  String sql = "SELECT * FROM alumons WHERE nombre = ? AND pass = ?";

Comment: No, por montar el SQL me refiero a montarlo **COMPLETO**, con valores incluidos... lo mismo que pasarías por la consola SQL: `SELECT* FROM alumnos WHERE nombre = 'Giorgio' AND pass='1234'`. Con `Statement` no puedes reemplazar los placeholders (los `?`).

Comment: ok entonces de lo que el usario introduce en el TextBox se lo paso a la consulta asi es como funciona el Statement